# Pom file showing the exceptions

Tags: maven, pom.xml

CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.5.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.5.1 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.5.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.5.1/maven-compiler-plugin-2.5.1.pom. Error code 501, HTTPS Required

Comment: You are using http access to central repository which is turned off for a longer time... take a deeper look here: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334-Central-501-HTTPS-Required. furthermore please upgrade your maven installation and your used plugins...

Comment: He said to replace Replace http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ with https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/   where I have to replace this.Where this will be there?

Comment: What maven version/JDK version do you use? And it looks like you are using a outdates plugin versions...

Comment: I am trying to uninstall the maven software in eclipse.Even that is also not working.

Comment: Which eclipse version? Upgrade to most recent version.

Comment: yes eclipse was 2017 version.Now I have downloaded new one.Its working fine.Thank you.